# How do you make a kill command that responds to pinging the bot in a different way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want the bot to normally kill someone, lets say if you write ".kill @user" it will kill the user,

if i ping the bot, i want it to say something else.
my current code:

```
const Discord = require ('discord.js');

const { FILE } = require('dns');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = ".";

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('bot is online...');
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/)
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'kill'){
        module.exports = {
            name: 'kill',
            description: "This command is used to kill people... It might backfire!",
            execute(message, args){
        if (message.content.includes('<@(my bots id)>')){
            var tries = ['Kindly stop that.', 'Don\'t do that.', 'No.', 'Don\'t even think about it.', 'Smh.'];
        
            var tries_response = tries[Math.floor(Math.random()*tries.length)];
        
            message.channel.send(tries_response);

            const taggedUser = message.mentions.users.first();
            var kills = ["a", "lot", "of", "random", "kills"];
            var weapon = ["a", "lot", "of", "random", "weapons"];
    
            var kills_response = kills[Math.floor(Math.random()*kills.length)];
            var weapon_response = weapon[Math.floor(Math.random()*weapon.length)];
    
            if(message.mentions.users.size){
                message.channel.send(kills_response + ' ' + `${taggedUser.username}` + ' ' + weapon_response);
            } else if(!message.mentions.users.size){
                message.channel.send('You can try to run that command again, but mention someone so they can die.')
            }
        }
    }
}
})

client.login('bruh')
```

examples of what i want the bot to do:

.kill @user

"a goose killed user with a gun"

.kill @mybot

"Smh."

Answer (score 2):

First of all, not sure what the `module.exports` is doing there inside your event listener's callback, probably you just copy-pasted it wrong.

Anyway, if you know the bot's ID, you can store it in a variable (`botId`) and check the mentioned member's ID to this. If it matches, you just send a different response.

Check out the working code below:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'ping') {
    client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
  } else if (command == 'kill') {
    let botId = '8047492xxxx66282';
    let mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first();

    if (!mentionedMember)
      return message.channel.send('You forgot to mention someone');

    if (mentionedMember.id === botId) {
      let tries = [
        'Kindly stop that.',
        "Don't do that.",
        'No.',
        "Don't even think about it.",
        'Smh.',
      ];

      let response = tries[Math.floor(Math.random() * tries.length)];

      return message.channel.send(response);
    }

    let kills = ['a shadow', 'a goose', 'an octopus', 'a cat'];
    let weapon = ['a watermelon', 'a spoon', 'a picture of JFK', 'a piece of hair', 'a coconut'];
    let responseKills = kills[Math.floor(Math.random() * kills.length)];
    let responseWeapon = weapon[Math.floor(Math.random() * weapon.length)];

    return message.channel.send(`${responseKills} killed ${mentionedMember} with ${responseWeapon}`);
  }
});
```

[image]